# Producer Consumer model for BFS

Tags: c#, multithreading, algorithm, producer-consumer

I'm trying to do a maze solving algorithm, and I've decided to use BFS to try and find the shortest path (since I have no way of determining how close I am to the exit, I'm not sure how I could use something A*).

In an effort to speed things up, I've decided to go with a multi-threaded approach, and have 4 simultaneous threads exploring all four possible directions of travel from the current cell (with just a single thread doing the actual movement)

My current solution looks something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        fullCount.WaitOne(); //fullCount is initialized to 4
        queueLock.WaitOne(); // binary semaphore for queue access
        if (cellQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            parent = cellQueue.Dequeue();
        }
        queueLock.Release();

        if (parent.isAtEnd())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We made it!");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Currently at X: {0}, Y:{1}", parent.x, parent.y);

        Thread travelNorth = new Thread(() => explore("NORTH", parent.north));
        Thread travelSouth = new Thread(() => explore("SOUTH", parent.south));
        Thread travelEast = new Thread(() => explore("EAST", parent.east));
        Thread travelWest = new Thread(() => explore("WEST", parent.west));

        travelNorth.Start();
        travelSouth.Start();
        travelEast.Start();
        travelWest.Start();
        }
    }
}

// function that each thread calls
static void explore(string direction, string status) 
{
    if (status == "UNEXPLORED) 
    {
        bool movableDirection = lookAhead(direction);
        if (movableDirection) 
        {
           Cell tempCell = grabCell(direction); //gets the cell that lies in specified direction
           queueLock.WaitOne();
           cellQueue.Enqueue(tempCell);
           queueLock.Release();
           fullCount.Release(); //allow main thread to continue if queue is empty.
    }
}
```

I'm having an issue is that my `Main()` method stops at the `fullCount.WaitOne();` line, indicating that the queue is empty and we are waiting for the queue to not be empty. And quite annoyingly (as with all mulithreaded problems), I don't see where/why I'm getting the situation where my queue is empty unless I somehow entered a loop in the maze.

Comment: Does exploring in some direction mean going strictly in that direction and never turn?

Comment: Exploring means going strictly in that one direction, and only for the surrounding cells (i.e. if going NORTH, only go NORTH one cell etc...)

Comment: I have some doubt about this way of using threads. You need to be aware of making new thread cost and all stuff you need to do to avoid deadlock etc.

Comment: Add a `Thread.Sleep(500)` at the end of your main loop and for a very small maze. Would it make your problem arise very early?

Comment: Besides, please add variable declarations to question.